# How to change omnibox search engine tld in Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I want to change google chrome default omnibox search engine tld from google.ro to google.fr. I'm currently in Romania and Chrome stupidly picked the location where I installed it (windows machine). Actually it's not as stupid as the fact that I spent several hours googling how to change this language and found nothing helpful. I tried to turn off chrome and replace all google.ro to google.fr in Preferences file, it didn't help.
Unfortunately I'm too much bound to "Corporation of Good" apps and services and can't just switch to another browser. In addition it's very nice equipped for web-development.
So the question is there a way to change tld for omnibox search in chrome or I'm doomed to use google in unfamiliar language all several months of my business trip?

Comment: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/07/change-chromes-search-engine-to.html

Comment: @SLaks I don't need google.com, and I still tried this trick, didn't work for me.

Comment: Google automatically redirects you to a localised site (in your case, google.ro) based on the location your IP address gives. Either use another search engine, or use a VPN to make Google think you are in France (to get the google.fr tld)